# Windows: Can I determine which process last used a particular port?

Tags: windows, port

Can I determine which process has used a particular port, specifically port 137, in the past on a Windows system? I tried `netstat -anob` without success as it gives only the list of processes which are currently using different ports. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such functionality on netstat to check past information.

Only place I can think of it's the eventlog, which in the specific case that the process/service generated an event while binding to that port you will be able to see which process was.

Regarding the 137 port, if we are talking about UDP then likely was the netbios process which is part of all windows installations, check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) for more information.